# Is it correct to cancel CountDownTimer in onFinish() method?

Tags: java, android

Does it make sense or is it a good way to feel safe to cancel CountDownTimer in onFinish() method?

```
my_count_downtimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        is_active=true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        cancelmycountdowntimer();
    }

}.start();




public void cancelmycountdowntimer(){
if(my_count_downtimer!=null){
   my_count_downtimer.cancel();
   is_active=true;
  }
}
```

Comment: No. There's no point to cancel something that's already finished. You can just have `public void onFinish() { is_active = false; }`

Comment: okay, so in onFinish() method, the countdowntimer is freed autimatically right? So I only have to cancel the timer in onDestroy() method if only if it is running and it has not finished, right? In conclusion, when onFinish() is executed the memory is freed automatically?

Answer (score 1):

inside `cancelmycountdowntimer` method you should probably have `is_active=false;`, besides that you probably should `null`ify your `my_count_downtimer`. if `null`ing it isn't needed then there is no reason for calling `cancel` when timer already finished (and called `onFinish`), but you probably still need to set `is_active=false;`

```
is_active=true;
my_count_downtimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        is_active=false;
    }

}.start();
```

note that you should cancel this timer when user leave `Activity` or `Fragment` before timer finish, if not you may get `NullPointerException` or memory leak

Comment: "note that you should cancel this timer when user leave Activity or Fragment before timer finish, if not you may get NullPointerException or memory leak" -- okay, but if the my_count_downtimer has finished, should I also cancel it when user leave Activity or when it is finished the countdowntimer is freed automatically?